# does swift not allow initialization in function parameters?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This first block generates a generic Swift Compile Error (doesn't even point to the line)

```
let screenDivision = size.width / 5;
var game1 = SKSpriteNode(color: .redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 2 * screenDivision, height: size.height));
```

This second block works fine.

```
let screenDivision = size.width / 5;
var a = CGSize(width: 2 * screenDivision, height: size.height)
var game1 = SKSpriteNode(color: .redColor(), size: a);
```

Why? I'd hate to run into this error again and not remember where I wrote such code.

(I also need to pass it a variable, not a constant? Wtf... [if I change var a, to let a, I get the compile error])

Comment: I haven't done extensive research to discover when this was fixed, but at least as of Swift 3.2, this is no longer an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error goes away if you include `UIColor` in your call to `redColor`:

```
let screenDivision = size.width / 5;
var game1 = SKSpriteNode(
    color: UIColor.redColor(),
    size: CGSize(width: 2 * screenDivision,
    height: size.height)
)
```

I am not aware of the ability to leave out type names for class methods. I am only aware of that being possible with Enumeration cases. The Swift programming guide [mentions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_221) specifically that this is possible with enumerations but says nothing in the [type method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_363) section.

I am actually surprised that the second version works. For now, I would always include the type name unless you are referring to an enumeration case.

Comment: FYI, ["Enumeration Case Pattern"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_1012) and "Implicit Member Expression" are different in grammatical meaning.

Comment: `.redColor()` should compile in this context.

Comment: @rintaro, I was not aware of that being in the grammar, thanks for pointing that out. It is still pretty vague on when this is possible. For example, is this only possible when the class method is on the class that is being returned or will it work for any class method that returns the required type?

Comment: Drewag your answer directly solved my problem. Thanks very much! It may be a bug with swift, but your solution does fix the problem, so cheers mate.

Comment: @drewag see rintaro's answer.

Comment: @0x141E I did. All he showed was the grammar of the language, which just says "in a context where type inference can determine the implied type". That does give us any information as to when the compiler should be able to do that (not that I am blaming him for that, but I haven't seen any other documentation around this)

Comment: @drewag since SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor,size:CGSize) expects an SKColor as its first parameter, the type is inferred and you can use the abbreviated .redColor() instead of SKColor.redColor().

Comment: @0x141E, I understand how this specific scenario is supposed to work. But I am wounding the more specific rules around all of the scenarios. For example, in this scenario the parameter is expecting a UIColor and it allows using a class method from UIColor that returns a UIColor. Would it allow some random class's class method that returns a UIColor like MyClass.myFavoriteColor(). I can of course just try out other scenarios but I was hoping for some documentation to give more concrete rules around it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, it's a compiler bug.

In this case, ["Implicit Member Expression"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-XID_807) should be performed.

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case **or a class method**, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the following form:
>
> > `.`<kbd>member name</kbd>

I reproduced exact the same problem with this code:

```
class MyClass {
    class func create() -> MyClass { return MyClass() }
}

func f(arg:MyClass!, arg2:Int) { } 

f(.create(), 1)

/*
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %.asUnsubstituted = bitcast %C4test7MyClass* %6 to i64
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
*/
```

or even with `enum`:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case Case1
}

func f(arg:MyEnum!, arg2:Int) { } 

f(.Case1, 1)

/*
0  swift                    0x00000001062d8a68 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x00000001062d8f54 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8a314f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fd8085362e8 _sigtramp + 2116162536
4  swift                    0x00000001056e8e98 emitApplyArgument((anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction&, swift::SILValue, swift::SILParameterInfo, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 456
5  swift                    0x00000001056e5f1d swift::SILVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction, void>::visit(swift::ValueBase*) + 34605
6  swift                    0x00000001056dcbab swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9179
7  swift                    0x0000000105656347 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitLazyDefinitions() + 199
8  swift                    0x00000001056c9966 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 2038
9  swift                    0x00000001056ca2e3 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51
10 swift                    0x000000010561f5f4 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 5444
11 swift                    0x000000010561c96d main + 1677
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff90b525c9 start + 1
13 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000010 start + 1867176520
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file test.swift -target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 -target-cpu core2 -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name test -o /var/folders/kb/xgglxb597sv6h8b744d5vft00000gn/T/test-4cf5cc.o 
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @top_level_code<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
*/
```

Both cases, removing `!` from the function parameter solves the problem.

Let's say: **"DO NOT USE implicit member expression for implicitly unwrapped optional context"**

Comment: Good catch, and nice answer. Be sure to [file that bug](http://bugreport.apple.com)!

Comment: Thanks, this makes me feel more sane.

Unfortunately I don't have control over the SKSpriteNode initializer to change it's prototype parameters, so I have to use drewag's solution.

This was a pretty cool thing you found though. I'll submit the bug, although im sure someone else has already submitted it.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted to realize "what causes this bug"

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is out-of-date: at least as of Swift 3.2, the crash no longer occurs.