# Calling a Swift class factory method with leading dot notation?

Tags: swift

In a recent question, the poster had this interesting line of code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
```

I was surprised to see this.  I've only ever seen the *leading dot* notation used for enum values.  In this case, `backgroundColor` is of type `UIColor?` and `whiteColor` is a class method on `UIColor` that returns a `UIColor`.

Why does this work?  It this a legitimate way to call a factory method?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This **feature** is called "[Implicit Member Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID394)"

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case **or a class method**, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the following form:
>
> > `.`<kbd>member name</kbd>

---

But, as of right now, I advise you *should not* use this feature in `Optional` or `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` context.

Although this works:

```
// store in Optional variable
let col: UIColor?
col = .redColor()

// pass to function
func f(arg:UIColor?) { println(arg) }
f(.redColor())
```

This crashes the compiler :(

```
func f(arg:UIColor?, arg2:Int) { println(arg) }
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^ just added this.
f(.redColor(), 1)
```

The compiler has some bugs. see: [does swift not allow initialization in function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26921177/3804019)

Comment: It should be noted that, at least in Swift 3.2, that last example does _not_ crash the compiler, and in fact (after inserting the omitted argument labels) runs just fine.

Answer (score 18):

Looks like the rule is: if a type has a static method that returns that type, you can skip the type’s name if the return type is already determined:

```
struct S {
    static func staticmethod() -> S {
        return S()
    }
    static var staticproperty: S {
        return S()
    }
}

let s1: S = .staticmethod()
let s2: S = .staticproperty
```

I wonder if this is intentional, or a side-effect of the implementation of Enums which, given this feature, could maybe be thought of as syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
struct FakeEnum {
    let raw: Int
    static var FirstCase:  FakeEnum  { return FakeEnum(raw: 0) }
    static var SecondCase: FakeEnum  { return FakeEnum(raw: 1) }
}

let e: FakeEnum = .FirstCase
```

Answer (score 9):

I could not find anything along the lines in the documentation.  However, the way it works, I believe, is that Swift knows which type is being in context from `self.view.backgroundColor`, therefore expression starting directly with a dot should be a static on that type (either a static method or static property).

The following works nicely:

```
struct Foo {
    static func fooMethod() -> Foo {
        return Foo()
    }

    static var fooProperty: Foo = Foo()
}

var foo: Foo

foo = .fooMethod()

foo = .fooProperty
```