# Implicit Member Expression in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-radar

I've ran into a somewhat inconsistent behavior in regards to [Implicit Member Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID394) in Swift:

```
import UIKit

let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .brownColor() # works
button.setTitleColor(.brownColor(), forState: .Normal) # doesn't work
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: .Normal) # works
```

When using the leading dot notation in an assignment all works as expected. When using it as a parameter to a function however swift will throw  a complier error (the playground just crashes). To complicate the situation, the `UIControlState` enum properly inserts the implicit member expression value.

Is this a bug?

Comment: This seems to be a bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808977/1187415: *"as of right now ... you should not use this feature in Optional or ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional context."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and was fixed at least in the latest Swift version 2.1