# What is the Swift syntax " .bar" called?

Tags: swift, syntax, naming

Swift has this handy syntax:

```swift
enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz
}


func hoge(foo: Foo) {
}


hoge(foo: .bar) // This
```

Which is mirrored in places other than `enum`s:

```
struct Qux {
    static let `default` = Qux()
}


func hoge(qux: Qux) {
}


hoge(qux: .default) // This
```

I am not sure what to call this in conversation / tickets. Maybe "type-inferred dot syntax"? I'm unsure. **Does this syntax have an official name?** If so, what is it?

Comment: `enum Foo {  case .bar }` does not compile

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794089/calling-a-swift-class-factory-method-with-leading-dot-notation/28808977#28808977.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called an *implicit member expression*. From [the grammar section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/implicit-member-expression):

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member
>   of a type, such as an enumeration case or a type method, in a context
>   where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the
>   following form:
>
> **.**`member name`
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> var x = MyEnumeration.someValue
> x = .anotherValue
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Is this applicable to other languages? (for example, I was thinking of drafting a proposal to bring this to Kotlin) Or is this a Swift-proprietary term invention?

Comment: @BenLeggiero I don't see why the term can't be applied to other languages that have the concepts of type members and expressions. Though that being said, doing a quick Google search reveals that the term doesn't appear to be used much outside of Swift. Although it's a generic enough term that I don't *think* it could be claimed as proprietary – though I have no expertise in that area.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145):

> The values defined in an enumeration (such as north, south, east, and west) are its enumeration cases.

Comment: I"m not sure I've communicated properly... I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Based on your edit @Hamish has the answer, his is not specific to `enum`s like mine.