# In Swift why can the class name of a variable (not an Enum) be omitted in this declaration?

Tags: swift

```
let size: CGSize = .zero // .zero is a variable, not an Enum
```

Rather than:

```
let size: CGSize = CGSize.zero
```

.zero is a variable, so why am I allowed to omit the class name?

Comment: This is still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023274/what-is-the-swift-syntax-bar-called (as was your previous, now deleted, question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645304/swift-why-can-you-omit-the-class-name-of-a-static-variable). From the answer: *"An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an **enumeration case or a type method,** in a context where type inference can determine the implied type."*–  If it does not work with your own struct then please show a [mcve].

Comment: “I've created my own struct with a static property and try to declare a variable using dot notion, and it does not work”—edit your question to show your code. Otherwise we can't diagnose your problem.

Comment: struct Age {
 static var joe = 25
 static let sam = 20
}

let joesAge: Age = .joe  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
let samsAge: Age = .sam  // THIS DOES NOT WORK

Comment: let joesAge: Int = Age.sam. This works. The variable has to be Int. Which was a mistake in my previous comment. However, I still cannot omit the Struct name.

Comment: @Joe: You compare apples with oranges. `let size: CGSize = .zero` compiles because `zero` is a static member of `CGSize`. `let joesAge: Int = .sam` does not compile because `sam` is *not* a static member of `Int`.

Comment: I rushed the example. I do understand that. I don't understand how to create a struct with a variable, and then declare an instance of that struct with a variable type in dot notion. Which is what: let size: CGSize = .zero; seems to be doing. .zero is a variable.

Comment: @Joe: `CGSize` has a static property `zero` **of type CGSize.** – You can do the same with your custom struct `Age` if it has a static property of type `Age`.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. This answered my question.

Comment: How can I delete this question as a duplicate? It won't allow me because users have commented.

Comment: @Joe my answer answered your question too. The problem is you don’t read the answers you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Swift syntax " .bar" called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023274/what-is-the-swift-syntax-bar-called)

Answer (score 2):

It is a static property of a type that is known in advance and has, itself, the same type. Thus the type can be omitted.  These are equivalent:

```
let size = CGSize.zero
```

And

```
let size: CGSize = .zero
```

Because `CGSize.zero` is itself a CGSize.

A very common example is:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .red
```

where the type UIColor is known in advance, and `UIColor.red` is itself a UIColor.

That is completely parallel to an enum. `MyEnum.myCase` is itself a MyEnum.

Here’s an example of how to declare your own such struct:

```
struct Age {
    let value : Int
    static let retirement = Age(value:65)
}
```

Now you can say

```
let howOld : Age = .retirement
```

Comment: I've created my own struct with a static property and try to declare a variable using dot notion, and it does not work. is it only for Apple structs? Maybe there using Subscripts in their Structs?

Comment: the variable needs to be static and the scope becomes available throughout the project.

Comment: struct Age {
 static var joe = 25
 static var sam = 20
}

let joesAge: Int = Age.sam // THIS WORKS
let joesAge: Int = .sam // THIS DOES NOT WORK

Comment: Because Age and Int are different types. In the example you originally gave, CGSize is the type of its own static property `CGSize.zero`.

Comment: I rushed the example. I do understand that. I don't understand how to create a struct with a variable, and then declare an instance of that struct with a variable type in dot notion. Which is what: let size: CGSize = .zero; seems to be doing. .zero is a variable.

Comment: But CGSize is an example of how to do it! Or even simpler just conform to RawRepresentable.

Comment: I added an Age example for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in *The Swift Programming Language* as [“Implicit Member Expression”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID394):

> ### Implicit Member Expression
>
> An *implicit member expression* is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case or a type method, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the following form:
>
> ```
> .member name
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> var x = MyEnumeration.someValue
> x = .anotherValue
> ```
>
> #### GRAMMAR OF A IMPLICIT MEMBER EXPRESSION
>
> *implicit-member-expression* → `.` identifier

Comment: I'm not talking about Enum types, I am talking about variables!

Comment: What does the book say? It says “a member of a type”. A variable is a member of a type if it is a `static` or `class` variable.