# What's the difference between ".colorName" and "Color.colorName" in SwiftUI? Why is it showing two outputs if they are the same?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was learning Swift UI and I faced an issue regarding colors. If I use `background(.red)` then my output of the button looks like this **(Line number 39)**.
[image]

But the weird part is that if I use `background(Color.red)` then my output of the button looks like this **(Line number 39)**.

[image]

Now my questions are

1. Why two different outputs?
2. What's the actual difference between `Color.red` and `.red`?
3. When to use `Color.red` and `.red`?

Full code is given below

**Using `.red` code**

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Dicey-SwiftUI
//
//  Created by Moh. Absar Rahman on 26/11/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var leftDiceNumber = 1
    @State var rightDiceNumber = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Image("diceeLogo")
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    
                    DiceView(n: leftDiceNumber)
                    DiceView(n: rightDiceNumber)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    leftDiceNumber = 2
                    rightDiceNumber = 2
                }) {
                    Text("Roll")
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .background(.red)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct DiceView: View {
    let n: Int
    var body: some View {
        Image("dice\(n)")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

**Using `Color.red` code**

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Dicey-SwiftUI
//
//  Created by Moh. Absar Rahman on 26/11/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var leftDiceNumber = 1
    @State var rightDiceNumber = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Image("diceeLogo")
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    
                    DiceView(n: leftDiceNumber)
                    DiceView(n: rightDiceNumber)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    leftDiceNumber = 2
                    rightDiceNumber = 2
                }) {
                    Text("Roll")
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct DiceView: View {
    let n: Int
    var body: some View {
        Image("dice\(n)")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

**Note: Please do not laugh at me. I am still a beginner who is trying his best to learn SwiftUI**

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47023274/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53664090/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [implicit member expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID394). in situations where the type can be inferred from other information, like return types, the actual type name can be omitted.

in

```
.background(Color.red)
```

it cannot be omitted, as the parameter isnt typed `Color`, but `some View`. it wouldn't know where to look for `red` if type was missing.

---

The difference that you see in the preview are not explainable by the code, there-for I suggest you execute it on the device, as it might be some unwanted artefact. I see a lot of those in the current Xcode version.

Comment: Is this the reason why the color of the button exceeded the height while using ```.red```?

Comment: no. did you run it on device, does it happen there too?

Comment: Actually this called [“implicit member expression”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID394), compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/28808977/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023368/1187415.

Comment: My bad. Xcode bug. Just ran both the codes and the output was same. Thanks for the info. I did not know that Xcode has these kinds of bugs. The reason why I posted this question is because it's showing two different outputs on my Xcode which was not supposed to happen.

Comment: @Moh.AbsarRahman: if that was the question that you really wanted answered, you should ask for that. now this information that might be useful to others is hidden in these comments.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have edited my question. I was so confused at that time and so many questions were spinning inside of my head