# Pass in argument predefined or custom function in swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass to setter as argument one of predefined functions (in enum maybe or static) or custom function in closure.
like UIColor to UIView.backgroundColor (i can set .black or UIColor(...)). How can I do it with my custom class?

```
class MyClass {
    var fun: ((String)->Void)?       

}

var obj = MyClass()
obj.fun = {print($0)} .   // It works now
obj.fun = .predefinedFunc // It's how i want to be able do
```

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want to do is "implicit member access". Unfortunately, this is not possible on closure types like `(String) -> Void`, because it only works on enums, as well as types with static members. `(String) -> Void` doesn't and can't have any static members.

It seems like what you want is simply a bunch of predefined functions. This can be done with an enum:

```
enum Function {
    case predefinedFunc1
    case predefinedFunc2
    case predefinedFunc3 // name these properly!

    var closure: (String) -> Void {
        switch self {
            case .predefinedFunc1: return { print($0) }
            case .predefinedFunc2: ...
            case .predefinedFunc3: ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'll be able to do:

```
class MyClass {
    var fun: Function?     

}

var obj = MyClass()
obj.func = .predefinedFunc1
```

If you also want to include an option to use a custom function, add an extra case with an associated value:

```
enum Function {
    ...
    case custom((String) -> Void)

    var closure: (String) -> Void {
        switch self {
            case .predefinedFunc1: return { print($0) }
            ...
            case .custom(let f): return f
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
view.backgroundColor = .black
```

works because `black` is a *static property* of `struct UIColor`. The right-hand side is called an “implicit member expression,” see for example [What is the Swift syntax " .bar" called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47023274/1187415).

Function types are neither classes nor structs, and you cannot define a static property for a function type. Therefore an identical syntax is not possible.

What you can do is to define a “wrapper” `struct` for the function, with static properties for the predefined functions. Here is a simple example:

```
struct Fun {
    let f: (String) -> Void

    init(_ f: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.f = f
    }

    // Predefined functions:
    static var printer = Fun( { print($0) } )
    // ...
}

class MyClass {
    var fun: Fun?
}
```

And then you can do

```
let obj = MyClass()
obj.fun = Fun( { print($0) } ) // set to custom function
obj.fun = .printer             // set to predefined function
```

This approach also allows to *extend* the wrapper type by more predefined functions:

```
extension Fun {
    static var printReversed = Fun( { print($0.reversed()) } )
}

// ...
obj.fun = .printReversed
```

Answer (score 1):

Please define the func same as you callback func or nameless fun, then you can pass it as an argument.

```
class MyClass {
    var fun: ((String)->Void)?

}
//MARK:- you have to provide the same param and return type in your predefined func.
func printer(Str :String)->Void{
    print(Str)
}

var obj = MyClass()
obj.fun = {print($0)}
obj.fun = printer
```

Comment: Please check now, I have compiled. it's working fine. hope this is the target you want to achieve.