# Variable type with dot before name?

Tags: swift, xcode

What type of variable is e.g. .bottom? I want to declare such a variable or want to send passing data with this variable.

Comment: They are either static properties or just enumeration cases.

Comment: See [What is the Swift syntax “ .bar” called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47023274/1187415)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's value of [enum](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case north
    case south
    case east
    case west
}
```

When you have that enum like in example above then you can use that:

```
let compassPoint = CompassPoint.west
let compassPoint: CompassPoint = .west
```

When the type is known then you can use the syntax with `.`.

Comment: How to declare such a data type without knowing the specific enum parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It could be any type with a member called *bottom*. It has been omitted because the compiler can parse "implicit member expressions". It means that whenever the compiler can infer the type from the context, you do not need to write it. Back to your problem: you could do a "Command"-Click on the expression and let XCode tell you more about the context.