# What does .text and the dot mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am currently coding my own app and I was looking at a coding video for help and the person in the video was using `.text` and some other things that had dots in front of them like `.color` and `.shape`, which were variables declared and initialized already. I was wondering if anybody has a clear definition on what the `.text` means or what it does and what the overall dot means whenever you use it.

Comment: . is a operator to access methods and property of class

Comment: Related ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794089/calling-a-swift-class-factory-method-with-leading-dot-notation

Answer (score 9):

This feature is called "**Implicit Member Expression**"

An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case or a class method, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the following form:

.member name

For example : if you want to pick a color, in Swift4 you can simply do so:

```
let color: UIColor = .green
```

instead of typing :

```
let color : UIColor = UIColor.green()
```

Comment: So what would we use the .text for?

Comment: Like an example?

Comment: Oh never mind i understand it now.Thanks.

Comment: Why do we need the .text at the end?Why is it required?

Comment: .text is used to enter a string value. For example , if you have a label, to add a text to it you write :
aLabel.text = "some text"

Comment: .text use to get the text from UI components like UITextField, UILabel or UITextView. In other words, you can say if you want to access the text member of a UILabel object, then you can use like this: let title = label.text